# What is the pytest equivalent for distinguishing test iterations using subtests

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

[Distinguishing test iterations using subtests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests)

```
class NumbersTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_even(self):
        """
        Test that numbers between 0 and 5 are all even.
        """
        for i in range(0, 6):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                self.assertEqual(i % 2, 0)
```

Output:

```
FAIL: test_even (__main__.NumbersTest) (i=1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subtests.py", line 32, in test_even
    self.assertEqual(i % 2, 0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0

======================================================================
FAIL: test_even (__main__.NumbersTest) (i=3)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subtests.py", line 32, in test_even
    self.assertEqual(i % 2, 0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0

======================================================================
FAIL: test_even (__main__.NumbersTest) (i=5)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subtests.py", line 32, in test_even
    self.assertEqual(i % 2, 0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0
```

Without using a subtest, execution would stop after the first failure, and the error would be less easy to diagnose because the value of i wouldn’t be displayed.

When I run the above using pytest, then I don't see which test is failing. Does pytest not support this feature?

Answer (score 1):

U should consider parameterizing tests instead of running a for loop inside the test case.. that is the way pytest generates multiples instances of the same test for different input values..

https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html

The first example from that page shows:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "test_input,expected", [("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 6), ("6*9", 42)]
)
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected
```

When run, this calls `test_eval` three times, as:

```
test_eval(test_input="3+5", expected=8)
test_eval(test_input="2+4", expected=6)
test_eval(test_input="6*9", expected=42)
```

Like unittest subTests, if any of these invocations fail, the others are still run.

Comment: can you give example

Comment: do you know if there is a way to loop through files?

Comment: what do u mean by loop through files?? do u have a bunch of tests in a python file and want all the tests to be executed for a bunch of values like the range example you have?

Comment: I have just one test that i want to execute for list of files. Why cant pytest return which file failed when I use the same example as posted in the question?

Comment: pytest has a hook named pytest_generate_tests... you can dynamically parameterize any test.. in your case you can find the list of file from which ever directory you have it and pass them to the test.. that should solve.. pytest doc should have examples of the same..